# Eclipse Subclipse not identifying resources under source control

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I have used Subclipse, a Subversion plugin for Eclipse, in the past and it has always just worked on install but not now. I added it to my Eclipse Helios and it is not identifying any of my files that are under source control as such. It gives the message "Resource not managed" when I inspect a file I know is managed in the SVN Properties view.

I have verified that SVN is checked under Preferences > General > Appearance > Label Decorations and the settings under Preferences > Team > SVN look reasonable.

I am using Subclipse 1.6.13 and Eclipse 3.6.0.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two of my eclipse projects had some kind of problem, I deleted them from the package explorer (did not delete the project files just removed from package explorer) then imported them back in (File > import) and everything was fine. Nothing to do with helios.

Comment: During the process I also tried out subversive which did not work at first either until I right clicked on the projects and selected Team > Share Projects and hit ok.

Answer (score 1):

There's some discussion [here](http://subclipse.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=1047&dsMessageId=2625924) to the effect that it has to do with Eclipse + user permissions.  I can't verify personally, as I haven't fiddled with Helios yet.

That in mind, my answer is: if you aren't using some vital feature of Helios, don't migrate from Galileo (or older) yet.

Answer (score 0):

The quality of the SVN implementation - both Subclipse and Subversive leaves a lot to be desired - the latter being the lesser evil in my experience.

For me the only way to get a folder to be noticed (get the little ? icon) so that  'Add to version control' was working was to 'Right Click > Team > Disconnect' and then delete the `.svn` folder in the repository, and re-setup SVN through eclipse ('Share project').

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the 'src' directory.
solution:

1. copy the src directory to some other place, ex: c:\temp.
2. delete the src directory from eclipse project (via package or
   project expl.).
3. open tortoise SVN (right click/repo browser).
4. drag & drop (while pressing the Ctrl key) the src directory  to the
   wanted directory in SVN.
5. in eclipse do: team/synchronozied, then update.